# Getting the file name in Hadoop mapper using Hadoop Pipes

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

How can I get the ***input file*** name which is being executed in the `hadoop mapper` in `Hadoop Pipes?`

I can easily get file name in java based map reducer like

> FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();    String
>   filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();   System.out.println("File
>   name "+filename); System.out.println("Directory and
>   Filename"+fileSplit.getPath().toString());

but how can I get in C++;

Plz help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For streaming / pipes jobs, the job configuration is serialized to process environment variables.

The job configuration property that defines the input file is named `map.input.file`. The [PipeMapRed](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.4/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/PipeMapRed.java?view=markup) class which launches the C++ program is responsible for this serialization (`configure` method, line 151), and ensures that the job conf property names are escaped (`addJobConfToEnvironment` method line 206/266) - meaning that all non `a-Za-z0-9` characters are replaced with underscores (`safeEnvVarName` method, lines 276/284) - so the actual environment variable you're looking for in your c++ program will be named `map_input_file`.

I'm, not a c++ programmer, so i can't tell you how to obtain environment variables, but i'm sure it's simple enough.

Comment: I found out that in my hadoop job, according to syslog, `PipeMapRed` takes up the better part of the whole job time, that's about 10 mins, while map process just takes up less than 1 min, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **HADOOP 2.x** with Python:

```
file_name = os.environ['mapreduce_map_input_file']
```

Answer (score 1):

By parsing the `mapreduce_map_input_file`(new) or <del>`map_input_file`</del>(deprecated) environment variable, you can get the map input file name.

Notice:
The two environment variables are **case-sensitive**, all letters should be **lower-case**.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this in Python:

```
import os
filename = os.environ['map_input_file']
```

filename is the variable that you want - this will give you the filename that the mapper is working on.

Some other useful environment variables are:

- mapred_job_id = the full job id
- mapred_tip_id = the id of that specific mapper or reducer task

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggled with the same problem. And I found the solution.

```
void map(HadoopPipes::MapContext& context) {                                                                                         
    string path;
    path = context.getInputSplit();                                                                                                    
    path.erase(path.end()-1);
}
```

I posted only reading filename part. getInputSplit() method returns the whole path of the file + some unknown character at the end. I want pure path of the file so remove the end character of the string. I have no idea why the weired character is added end of the string but let's use it just by removing the end character~!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be able to print the filename

```
filepath = os.environ['mapreduce_map_input_file']

filename = os.path.split(filepath)[-1]

print filename
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)